# xml to use config file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I'm writing a script to run on a few different servers. I have 1000+ `*.job.xml` files that are holding paths.

I want to create a config file (preferable `.bat` or `.xml`) for that, so I won't need to change the path in every file. Only change the config file and let the other files get arguments from it .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <params>
    <param name ="path" value="mypath"/>
```

I want to get `mypath` from another file that will hold a few paths for me.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's a `*.job.xml` file? (It's also not at all difficult to write a script that uses XSLT to modify 1000 XML files, so maybe don't over-engineer this.)

Comment: it's a xml file to run from a job scheduler software kinda... I know I can find and replace text but then it won't be automatically and I will have to do so everytime I copy files from development server to production server and I have quiet few servers . I'd have to find a way to pass argument to xml from another xml or a batch file

Comment: Well there is a way to interlink XML files (xlink), but I honestly doubt that your "job scheduler software kinda" has implemented that. So modifying the files physically is likely your only way. Modifying them with XSLT is cheap and easy and can be made part of your deployment script, parameters and all. I don't see a problem there.

Comment: the problem is that I have 5 servers let's say . I will have to create a script for every server and define the paths instead of using a config file and read it on every server

Comment: So you would put the base files in a central location and all the servers pull it from there. In this case I would set a central config file with all the paths and write the logic so that the deployment script picks the appropriate config based on the current server's name. That would mean the only variable part would be the central config.

Comment: that is what I want to do ... but I need to pass this file's argument to my .xml jobs ... I can linked between 2     .batch files but can't do so between 2 xml s or a mix  xml and batch

Comment: That's why I keep saying that you need to modify the XML files physically as part of the deployment script.

Comment: haha ... I'm sure I can link between 2 files . thank you so much for trying tho much appreciated.  maybe others can come to it with a different pov

Comment: Wow. Well, you obviously know what you are doing, so I'm not sure why you are asking for help at all.

Comment: I can link between 2 batch files. I can pass arguments from xml to batch file . I can't see why I can't do the opposite and get argument from batch file or from another xml file . I mean no offence, I respect you but there must be a way I can use a config file for xml files.

Comment: It's not like things become real because it would be convenient for them to be real. I told you the name of the technology that can link XML files (xlink/xinclude). I also said that I would be really surprised if your proprietary scheduler software implemented those specifications, because they are extensions of vanilla XML. Bottom line: Unless your scheduler supports this (or a second, proprietary way of accepting parameters, look at its documentation), you are out of luck with linking or including XML files. I'm pretty sure a different pov will not change the basic facts.

Comment: my software is sos jobscheduler and I think it does support xinclude as it supports cdata ... but I don't know how to use it. I might be wrong but it sounds pretty intuitive. ... also mixing xml and .batch files is possible the other way,calling bat from xml using cdata . just the opposite is not so common online

Comment: CDATA is part of the basic XML specification, every software in the world that can read XML supports that. Look up how xinclude works and try if your scheduler supports it - you might be lucky. No, you can't call a batch file from within an XML file. You can store the text of a batch file in an XML file, but since XML (unlike batch) ist not a programming language you can't call squat from it.

Comment: I do call     .bat scripts from this xml files so I can run scripts . I pass arguments from the     <params> like that .    call path\script.bat %scheduler_param_args%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so who ever is using sos jobscheduler or I assume other schedulerside too can use shell script in order to call bat files.

```
<script language ="shell" >
    call path\config.bat 
    %parma_from_bat_file%
    %param2_from_bat_file%
     ..... your can send this parameters to another bat file
 <\script>
```

that will do what I was asking! thanks a lot